# Fastest way to convert 3-Channel Image to single vector of type T

Tags: image, opencv, c++11, optimization, c++17

I want to flatten 3-channel RGB image into a single vector of type T. In my case I am focused on *float* datatype. I wrote a function which is working fine. But I want to do this operation in less than 1MilliSecond. Here time cost is really a issue for me. Here is my code.

```
template<typename T>
inline std::vector<T> flatten_temp(cv::Mat frame_image)
{
    assert(!frame_image.empty());
    const int image_depth = frame_image.channels();
    frame_image.convertTo(frame_image, CV_32FC3);
    cv::Mat *planes =  new cv::Mat[image_depth];        
    
    // /** Split into BGR */
    cv::split(frame_image, planes);
    std::vector<T> flattened_image;
    
    flattened_image.assign(planes[0].begin<T>(), planes[0].end<T>());

    for (int i = 1; i < image_depth; ++i) {
        flattened_image.insert(flattened_image.end(), planes[i].begin<T>(), planes[i].end<T>());
    }
    frame_image.release();
    delete [] planes;
    return flattened_image;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wht is the resolution?

Comment: 1920x1080 resolution

Comment: It is likely that your image is *already* stored as a 1-dimensional array. See https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html, especially [`cv::Mat::isContinuous()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa90cea495029c7d1ee0a41361ccecdf3).

Comment: @beaker Yes, I know image is already stored as a 1-dimensional array. But I want 1-dimensional array in which first there is all R-channel values then G-channel and then B-channel value. That

Answer (score 0):

The `insert` on `flattened_image` *resize* the vector multiple times. Moreover, inserting may not be as fast as a plain `std::copy` (which can be done here). Indeed, if `planes[i].begin<T>()` and `planes[i].end<T>()` are trivial contiguous random iterators,  `std::copy` can even `memmove` or `memcpy` the memory block which is very fast.

Thus, you can first try to use `flattened_image.reserve(image_width * image_height * image_depth)`. Then, try to *allocate directly* the vector to the good size (filling it automatically with 0) and then do a `std::copy(planes[i].begin<T>(), planes[i].end<T>(), flattened_image.begin())`. The second version should be a bit faster. If channels are interleaved in memory, this code is not the most efficient as the input image will be read multiple time in memory. It is better in this case to *walk over the image line by line while interleaving channels*.

Note that you can also leverage *parallelism* and *SIMD instructions* if data are not contiguous to make this code even faster (OpenMP is probably a good start for that). Once optimized, such a computation should be bound by the memory hierarchy speed and thus take *less than 1 ms* for a 1920x1080x4 on almost all relatively-recent computers.